# Field read field write access in aspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am new to aspectJ. I would like to understand field read access and field write access pointcuts. Assume I have a private static string variable "name" in my class "Field".

```
private static String name;
```

I need to assign a value when name is read and throw exception when it is set.

Below is the aspectJ code.

```
package main.java.testaop.field;
public aspect FieldAspect {
pointcut getName() : get(private static String Field.name);
pointcut setName() : set(private static String Field.name);
before() : getName() {
"john";}
before() : setName() {
throw new Exception(); }
```

I am getting errors when compiling. I knew this is wrong. Can anyone help to make me understand how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to access private fields (which is possible, but a smell conceptually). In order to do that declare your aspect as privileged:

```
public privileged aspect FieldAspect { ... }
```

Comment: Many thanks .. kriegaex. Could you please suggest a tutorial for learning aspectJ for a beginner.

Comment: privileged works .. kriegaex. In get pointcut, I could assign the value I want. In any other places, if the value of Field.name is modified, then I am throwing runtime exception to avoid setting. Here, the issue I face is this "set" pointcut applies to "get" pointcut as well. How can I assign value of Field.name only in "get" pointcut.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Pointcut types `get()` and `set()` are not the same. Please explain better or update the question and show more code illustrating your problem.